# Best practice for device tree mixing GPIO and SPI in Linux Kernel device driver

Tags: linux-device-driver, gpio, spi, device-tree

As a personal challenge I'm developing a LKM for a SPI protocol device driver.

SPI slave device is implemented on MCU. There are 2 signal lines READY (slave has data to send) and BUSY (master is busy).

I'm using gpiod to setup the LKM as a gpio-consumer for the corresponding pins.

- READY is input and an IRQ handler is set up to initiate SPI transfer from the MCU.
- BUSY is output and is set until transfer has ended.

The device tree overlay looks like this.

```dts
         fragment@2 {
                target = <&spi0>;
                __overlay__ {
                        status = "okay";
                        #address-cells = <1>;
                        #size-cells = <0>;

                        spi_protocol_device@0 {
                                compatible = "mycomp,spi-protocol-device";
                                reg = <0x0>;
                                spi-max-frequency = <1000000>;
                                spi-bits-per-word = <8>;
                                busy-gpios = <&gpio 27 0>; 
                                ready-gpios = <&gpio 22 0>; 
                                status = "okay";
                        };
                };
        };
```

Wired up like this

```
        Rasperry Pi 4                                    STM32F411
        Kernel module                                    HAL

  +--------------------------+                        +------------+
  |                          |                        |            |
  |  Kernel module           |                        | Device     |
  |                          |                        |            |
  |   +-----------------+    |                        |            |
  |   |                 |    |                        |            |
  |   |                 |    |     READY              |            |
  |   | gpiod consumer  +----+-----<------------------+            |
  |   |                 |    |                        |            |
  |   |                 |    |     BUSY               |            |
  |   |                 +----+----->------------------+            |
  |   |                 |    |                        |            |
  |   |                 |    |                        |            |
  |   | spi protocol    |    |     CLK                |            |
  |   | driver          +----+----->------------------+            |
  |   |                 |    |                        |            |
  |   |                 |    |     MOSI               |            |
  |   |                 +----+----->------------------+            |
  |   |                 |    |                        |            |
  |   |                 |    |     MISO               |            |
  |   |                 +----+-----<------------------+            |
  |   |                 |    |                        |            |
  |   |                 |    |     CS0                |            |
  |   |                 +----+----->------------------+            |
  |   |                 |    |                        |            |
  |   +-----------------+    |                        |            |
  |                          |                        |            |
  +--------------------------+                        +------------+
```

It all works very well, but I think it looks weird to have gpiod settings in the SPI client section. Somehow I think that gpiod has nothing to do with the SPI section. I have also implemented it as platform device containing the gpiod part and the SPI part with only spi-relevant stuff. And it also work fine.

So my question is - Is there some best practice I've missed or is it just OK to add gpiod entries to the spi node?

Comment: I am totally lost. Can you provide a schematic on how the hardware is connected?

Comment: @0andriy Added schematic.

Comment: You could use a vendor prefix on your property names (e.g. replace `busy-gpios` with `mycomp,busy-gpios`) as suggested in [DOs and DON'Ts for designing and writing Devicetree bindings](https://docs.kernel.org/devicetree/bindings/writing-bindings.html).

Comment: According to the schematics the GPIOs are part of the SPI **slave** device to make it working. So, the provided DTS excerpt is correct (take into account @IanAbbott suggestion).

Comment: OTOH, I'm not sure who is the **master** for GPIOs in this case. Again, according to the schematics it's a RPi, which is **slave**. If this is true, the entire design is prone for chicken-egg issue, you have to redisign it before doing software.

Comment: @0andriy I think you meant master for the SPI bus, not master for the GPIOs. According to the schematic, the RPi is the SPI master because CLK and CS0 are output from the RPi.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The PI is the SPI master. I'll look into the DO and DON'Ts doc.

Comment: @IanAbbott, so if _ready_ is interrupt to RPi, what is the meaning of _busy_? In the Q it seems clearly stated that GPIOs are in inversed relationship to the SPI, which is chicken egg issue. If MCU interrupts CPU, CPU should simply read and analyze the data, no?

Comment: @0andriy I don't know how the *busy* signal is being used, but I guess it could mean something like "don't change the data because I'm currently trying to read it".

Comment: @IanAbbott, So it's rather something like _HOLD_, than _busy_. Again it's unclear why this even needed. Seems the flow control can be done differently without this additional wire, no?

Comment: @0andriy In theory, CS0 could be used as the busy signal unless several SPI messages are to be transferred between the master and slave during the busy period, and perhaps interleaved with SPI messages between the SPI master and a different SPI slave on the same bus (with a different CS line). Some SPI master controllers do weird things with the CS (a.k.a. SS) lines though, such as deasserting CS whenever the TX FIFO is empty, or glitching CS between each SPI word.

Comment: I'm trying to mimic a an imaginary super ADC using the builtin ADC on the MCU. The plan is to send a stream of packets of data from the MCU's ADC in continuous mode. So the PI will initiate (some command on SPI) the continues mode, get an interrupt from READY every time there is data, the PI will raise BUSY whenever it is busy transferring or doing other stuff.

Comment: I've changed changed the gpio naming to the DO and DON'T doc and works fine.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. HOLD may a better name instead of BUSY, but it does state that the PI is busy.

Comment: My initial question was grounded in that I thought the extra signal pins (READY, BUSY) didn't really belong into the SPI driver. Imagine fx. that there are multiple devices on the SPI bus - then it would be sufficient with a single BUSY signal to all devices. In that case I don't think the BUSY pin belongs in the SPI section - right?

Comment: Ahhh - OTOH the device tree describes the device - NOT the device driver. I think I finally got it :-)